# Order fields in model forms User and Profile and use form template

Tags: django, forms

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868941/post-profile-information-in-django-extended-user-model-user-has-no-profile) but I couldn't get the solutions provided to work. Instead of editing, I'm posting a new one with the modified code which uses a different approach (with two model forms)

## models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username



def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs["instance"]
    if kwargs["created"]:
        user_profile= Profile(user=user)
        user_profile.save()
post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

## forms.py

```
from django_superform import FormField, SuperForm

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label=("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput) 
    password2 = forms.CharField(label=("Confirm password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
        labels = {
            'username': ('Capser name'),
        }

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('location', 'birth_date')


class SuperProfile(SuperForm):
    signupform = FormField(SignUpForm)
    profileform = FormField(ProfileForm)
```

See that I'm using the Superform from [Django-superform](http://django-superform.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package. The reason for that is that I'm uing a form template in my html template as explained later in the template section.

## templates

### html page template : registration_form.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <h1>Create a capser account</h1>
    <table border="1">
        {{  userform.as_table }}

        {{ profileform.as_table }}
    </table>

    {% include 'home/form-template.html' %}

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create account</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

### form template : form-template.html

```
{% if messages %}
<ul>
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}

{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }}</span>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">{{ field }}</div>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.help_text }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

and the views.py with the new approach (importing fields from the two model forms

## views.py

```
class UserFormView(View):
    Userform_class = SignUpForm
    Profileform_class = ProfileForm
    template_name = 'home/registration_form.html'

    #display a blank form
    def get(self, request):
        userform = self.Userform_class(None)
        profileform=self.Profileform_class(None)

        return render (request, self.template_name, {'userform': userform, 'profileform': profileform})

    #process form data
    def post(self, request):
        userform = self.Userform_class(request.POST)
        profileform = self.Profileform_class(request.POST)


        if userform.is_valid() and profileform.is_valid():
            user = userform.save(commit=False)
            #user.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
            password = userform.cleaned_data['password1']
            user.set_password(password)
            username = userform.cleaned_data['username']
            first_name=userform.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name=userform.cleaned_data['last_name']
            email = userform.cleaned_data['email']
            user.save()

            new_profile = user_profile.objects.get(user = request.user)
            new_profile.objects.create(
                user=user,
                location=profileform.cleaned_data.get('location'),
                birth_date=profileform.cleaned_data.get('birth_date'))
            new_profile.save()

            #return user objects if credentials are correct
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('home:home')

        return render (request, self.template_name, {'userform': userform, 'profileform':profileform})
```

Now when I submit my form, I get the following error : `name 'user_profile' is not defined`

I thought that the `user_profil`e was the instance created at the end of my `model.py` file.
So if this doesn't work like so, how do I call the instance of my Profile model in the view ?

I've tried a lot of solutions and none worked so far.

Also, I initially wanted to use my form-template in order to display my form on the html page, but now that I use two model forms   userform and profileform, I wonder on how to use my form template (I tried with Superform without success).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it itself, `user_profile` is not defined.
A part of your code is not correct in your views.
You should deal with Django User Model, and after creating the instance, call your model `Profile` which is linked by `OneToOneField` to User from your `your_app.models`

```
from your_app.models import Profile

''' codes here '''
username = userform.cleaned_data['username']
first_name=userform.cleaned_data['first_name']
last_name=userform.cleaned_data['last_name']
email = userform.cleaned_data['email']
user.last_name = last_name
user.first_name = first_name
user.username = username
user.email = email
user.save()

new_profile = Profile.objects.create(
    user=user,
    location=profileform.cleaned_data.get('location'),
    birth_date=profileform.cleaned_data.get('birth_date')
)
new_profile.save()
```

That issue **UNIQUE constraint failed: home_profile.user_id** is because of the signal `post_save` is called by doing `new_profile.save()`. When it's called, it creates another profile with the same `user`, whereas `user` is already linked to the Profile when you had called `new_profile.save()` which has an `OneToOneField()` with `User`. So just remove the signal

Comment: Obviously, I missed that point. Now I get this error `UNIQUE constraint failed: home_profile.user_id`, I think due to the line `user=user` after the `Profile.objects.create`, but when I remove it I get this other error : `NOT NULL constraint failed: home_profile.user_id` Stuck again.

Comment: I have edited my answer and just below what I had written before, you will discover why you got these errors.

Comment: I marked as answered. Finally got it working. If I could vote 3 points on your answer I'd do that.